# Pegar o value de um button com javascript e executar função php

Tags: php, javascript

Olá!

Tenho um `button` no html com um `value` que é gerado apartir de um `foreach`, segue exemplo:

```
   foreach ($array_informado as $rows){
            if (mysqli_num_rows(consulta_imei($rows))>0) {
                $valores_consulta = mysqli_fetch_row(consulta_imei($rows));
                if ($rows = $valores_consulta[0]) {
                    if ($valores_consulta[21] == 0) {
                        echo "<tr class='table-success'>";
                        echo "<th scope='row'> 
                        <button type='submit btn-sm' id='liberar' value='".$rows."' onClick='capturaimei(this.value);' class='btn btn-success'>Lib</button>
                        <button type='submit btn-sm' id='bloquear' value='".$rows."' onClick='capturaimei(this.value);' class='btn btn-warning'>Bloq</button>
                        ";
                    }
```

Ao clicar em algum desses `buttons` (liberar ou bloquear) eu tenho que capturar o campo `value` e chamar uma função no php executando um `UPDATE` no banco de dados com esse value como parâmetro.

Nesse caso, a função javascript está dando um alert:

`function capturaimei(imei) {
  alert(imei);
}`

Essas são meus updates, onde os mesmos recebem o codigo como parâmetro:

```
function lock_travapda($imei){ // bloqueia os aparelhos que vem por parametro
include('con.php');
include_once('con.php');
$query_block_travapda   = "update jupiter_controle set travapda = 1 where imei in ($imei)";
$rs_block_travapda      = mysqli_query($con,$query_block_travapda) or die(mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_close($con);
```

A dúvida é a seguinte, como eu consigo chamar essa função `locktravapda` passando por parametro o código capturado com o `value` do button?

Segue prints da parte visual para facilitar entendimento:
[image: Imagem dos buttons com o retorno no alert]

Grato

Comment: Se for por AJAX, pesquise no site muito material sobre o assunto.

Answer (score -1):

Para um JavaScript executar um ".PHP" é necessário utilizar a [API Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) do JavaScript.

Esse código demonstra como você pode utilizar o Fetch que é uma API nativa do Javascript para executar um .PHP

```js
function capturaimei(imei) {
  // Formulário onde iremos inserir dados que serão enviados para o PHP
  var formdata = new FormData();
  // Estamos inserindo no formulário o valor que pegamos por parâmetro
  formdata.append("imei", imei);

  // Opções da requisição que será feita ao arquivo PHP.
  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formdata,
    redirect: 'follow'
  };

  // URL do arquivo PHP que contém a função a ser executada.
  // Lembre de alterar a URL de acordo com o seu projeto 
  fetch("http://localhost/locktravapda.php", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    // Se ocorrer algum erro durante o envio o JavaScript chama essa função
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

Agora será necessário criar um arquivo PHP separado para a função que você deseja executar no PHP.

Nesse exemplo criei um arquivo chamado locktravapda.php onde colocarei a lógica que será executada quando o JavaScript chamar esse arquivo .PHP

```php
<?php

// Salva o valor que foi enviado pelo JavaScript em uma variável.
$imei = $_POST['imei'];

// 
function lock_travapda($imei){ // bloqueia os aparelhos que vem por parametro
    include('con.php');
    include_once('con.php');
    $query_block_travapda   = "update jupiter_controle set travapda = 1 where imei in ($imei)";
    $rs_block_travapda      = mysqli_query($con,$query_block_travapda) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    mysqli_close($con);
}

// Chama a função passando como parâmetro o valor que foi enviado pelo JavaScript
lock_travapda($imei);
```

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar amanhã pela manhã

Desde já agradeço!!

Comment: Bom dia, sabe me dizer como eu testo se o formdata está com o valor correto?

Comment: Pergunto pois não estou conseguindo printar o valor da variavel $imei = $_POST['imei']; la na tela locktravapda

Comment: Boa tarde, para você testar se os valores estão sendo passados corretamente para o PHP basta você usar a depuração do navegador, se você estiver utilizando o Google Chrome pressione a tecla F12 e depois clique na aba Network, lá serão listadas todas as requisições feitas, então você deve clicar na requisição feita ao arquivo PHP e logo após clicar na aba Headers e descer até encontrar Form Data, pois lá serão listadas todos os parâmetros que foram enviados. Se mesmo assim você ainda ficou com dúvidas veja esse [vídeo](https://youtu.be/C7d-sZK90Dw). Espero ter ajudado boa sorte.